# Removing textbox using javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add and remove textboxes dynamically. Adding of textbox is working fine, but removing the textbox is not working. I've defined the onclick method on button element itself. Am I missing anything? There should be a simple mistake.

Here is my code

```
var container = document.getElementById('divArea');
function RemoveTextBox(div) {   
   document.getElementById("divArea").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}

function addTextBox(value){     
    return '<input name="newTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />' +
        '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTxtBox" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
}

document.getElementById('btnAdd').onclick = function() {
   var res = document.getElementById('val').value;  
  var div = document.createElement('DIV');
  div.innerHTML = addTextBox(res);
  container.appendChild(div);
}
```

My JS Fiddle     https://jsfiddle.net/2ddaw4zf/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2ddaw4zf/2/ - move the script to the bottom of body - In fiddle > script panel > Settings Icon(top right) > Load Type

Comment: In your console you should have seen an error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: RemoveTextBox is not defined` - because in fiddle the script is by default added to an `onload` handler, so your function `RemoveTextBox` is available only inside that handler, but you are trying to call it from the window scope resulting in the error

Comment: You're right. Got it. Its under Javascript settings icon.